# Is it a good idea to merge all helper classes into one gigantic class?

Tags: java, helper, convention

As I develop my software, I tend to find myself creating a whole ton of ThingyHelper.java, FooHelper.java, BarHelper.java etc. I counted, and in the current project that I am working on, there are something like over 40 classes that look something like this:

```
public final class FoobarHelper {
  // Prevent instantiation
  private FoobarHelper() {throw new AssertionError();}

  public static void doSomething() {}
  public static int foobar() {}
  // And many more
}
```

My question is this: Is it a good idea to merge all these classes into a huge Helper.java class? Looking around, there seems to be nothing written on this topic. My view is:

I should do it, because:

1. I don't have to remember which helper class is it in. (Was it FooHelper, or BarHelper?)
2. Just convenience. I don't have to decide if the new helper method deserves its own helper class, or if it fits into one of the existing 40 helper classes.
3. If I make a new helper method, and decided it deserves its own helper class, I will probably spend the rest of my day "hey, won't foobar() be better off in this new class?"
4. If #3 is true, other programmers would be like "where on earth did foobar() go? Its not in FoobarHelper!"

Is there a convention for helper classes, or if not, would it be a terrible idea?

Comment: Why are you creating so many helper classes? That is already a sign that there might be something wrong with the design of your code.

Comment: you should really think about your code when you are creating this much helper classes.

Comment: I suspect that this question may get close as being too broad/opinion based.  Some people would say yes merge them, others no.  And others still will say why do you have any helpers at all or to only merge helpers that are related; the JDK libraries have Objects, Arrays, Bits, Collections etc.  At the end of the day, give it a try and see what is most readable and maintainable for you.

Comment: **Cohesion**. That's the operating principle. Will there be cohesion between any of the utility methods if they're merged into a single class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I argue that your problem is not the fact that you have too many of those classes, it is that you need these classes altogether.

It is the core idea of object-orientation to merge functionality and data into objects which then represent your program flow. Without knowing your application, your utility classes suggest that you use inanimate bean classes which are then handled by a layer of service functions. This is a sign of procedural programming and nothing you want to implement with Java.

Besides that, there is no reason to merge your utility methods. So I would answer **no** to your question. There are some legitimate uses of utility classes such as Java's `Math`, `Collections` classes (those would also suite better as object methods but the language limits / limited this sort of definition) and you might just have encountered one of them. Note how Java decided to group such utility methods by their semantics. It makes sense to define utility methods in one name space such that your IDE can help you to pick a function when you only type the class (which does not represent a true class but rather a function namespace in this context). In the end, it is about finding a balance. If you have a single utility method per class, it is difficult for others to locate these methods as they need to know about the class's name. If there is only one utility class, it might be problematic to locate a function of all those offered. Think about the utility class as a form of navigation helper (name space) and decide after what you find intuitive.